# type of the data from mysql

Tags: python, mysql

Here is my code in Python:

```
queryuniq = "SELECT COUNT(distinct src_ip), COUNT(distinct video_id)FROM video"
cur.execute(queryuniq)
uniq = []
uniq = cur.fetchall()
print uniq
ip = str(uniq[0])
video = str(uniq[1])
fd2.write("There are %d ip addresses and %d video in total" %(int(ip), int(video)))
```

This is the value of "uniq" variable I got:

```
 ((2052L, 163581L),)
```

And this error message:

```
 fd2.write("There are %d ip addresses in total" %(int(ip)))
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '((2052L,),)'
 video = str(uniq[1])
 IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I just simply want to count the distinct items in a column in the database, and print the INT value in a file.

Can anyone explain why the SELECT command return a weird data format like ((2052L, 163581L),) ? Don't understand why there is a "L"after the number..

How can I solve this problem? Many thanks!

Comment: check the data in your table, most probably it contains the data in the weird format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uniq` is a tuple of tuples (each entry at the outer level represents a database *row*, within which there is a tuple of *column values*).

You query always returns one row. Therefore the outer tuple always contains one element, and you could fix your code by replacing:

```
uniq = cur.fetchall()
```

with

```
uniq = cur.fetchall()[0]
```

Also, the conversions from int to string and then back to int are unnecessary.

To summarize, the following is a tidied up version of your code:

```
queryuniq = "SELECT COUNT(distinct src_ip), COUNT(distinct video_id)FROM video"
cur.execute(queryuniq)
uniq = cur.fetchall()[0]
ip, video = uniq
fd2.write("There are %d ip addresses and %d video in total" %(ip, video))
```

Answer (score 2):

There several things wrong with your code.

Firstly, `cur.fetchall()` - as the name implies - fetches all the results from the query. Since Python does not know that your query only returns a single row, it still returns a tuple of all rows. So `uniq[0]` does not refer to the first field in the row, it refers to the first row in the result.

Since you know you only want one row, you could use `cur.fetchone()`.

Secondly, why are you converting the results to strings then converting them back to ints? That seems pointless. They are in the correct format already - `L` just means they are 'long ints'.